# Starting a custom theme using Zen

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-zen

I'm confused when trying to create a Zen subtheme for Drupal 7. First of all I'm sorry if this is a silly question butI'm not an expert on CSS.

Basically I want to set a fixed height for the navigation menu shown on the following picture: (The one with the Home link)

[image: Subtheme]

I have tried several ways to achieve a fixed height on the navigation div(height:200px, overflow:auto, float:left) however for all of those methods the navigation div overlaps the content. So basically the question is why is this happening? and how could I avoid that?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following CSS code snippet:

```
#nav
{
    height: 200px !important;
}
#nav:after
{
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Hope this works... Muhammad.